# LinkedIn API Search Posts

Tags: api, search, linkedin-api

Is there any such LinkedIn API by which we can get or search contents by keyword like we do in normal LinkedIn web page?

I have tried the api https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts but it response that

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Resource posts does not exist",
    "status": 404
}
```

Comment: Are you able to get search results from LinkedIn? I could not find api

Comment: @SandT not yet. Did you?

Comment: No.. thanks for reply.. looks like it does not exist